# ExpandableListView context menu

Tags: android

I'm trying to add a context menu to my `ExpandableListView`. I've implemented `onCreateContextMenu()` and `onContextItemSelected()` but if I hold my finger on a menu item context menu doesn't appear. What's my mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ops, I've just found a solution:

```
    registerForContextMenu(getExpandableListView());
```